# What causes this: Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, object

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in plugins/newsarticles/controller/NewsArticleController.php on line 29

I can see where it is erroring, line 29 is this line:

```
$sqlFetch = $this->model->getAllNewsArticlesByDate();
```

Below I have submitted my code, can anyone shed any light on this?

```
<?php
require_once("plugins/newsarticles/model/NewsArticleDB.php");
class NewsArticleController
{
    private $model;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->model = new NewsArticleDB();
    } //end constructor

        /**
    *Grab all the News Articles using the function
    *Filter by date
    *return the most recent 10
    */  
    function newsArticleHome()
    {
        //Grab the News Articles by date
        $sqlFetch = $this->model->getAllNewsArticlesByDate();
        foreach ($sqlFetch as $row)
        {

            //Insert posts into an object array
            $objNewsArticle[] = new NewsArticle($row['newsId'],$row['newsTitle'], $row['newsPreview'], $row['newsDisplayPicture'],  $row['newsContet']." ".$row['newsCategories'], $row['newsSubmissionDate']); 
        }

        //Count the array incase it's less than 10 posts
        //If it's more than 10, then set to 10, if it's less then set to x
        if(count($objNewsArticle) > 10)
        {
           $tempObjectCount = 10;
        }
        else
        {
            $tempObjectCount = count($objNewsArticle);
        }
        //Store them in an array for output
        for($tempLoopNumber = 0; $tempLoopNumber<$tempObjectCount; $tempLoopNumber++)
        {
            $recentNewsArticles[$tempLoopNumber] = $objNewsArticle[$tempLoopNumber];
        }
        return $recentNewsArticles;
    }

    function newsArticleId($id)
    {
        //Grab the Posts by date
        $sqlFetch = $this->model->getAllNewsArticlesByDate();
                $tempOptions = $sqlFetch->fetchAll();
        $tempOpNumber = count($tempOptions);


        for($tempNewsArticleNumber = 0; $tempNewsArticleNumber<$tempOpNumber; $tempNewsArticleNumber++)
        {
            if($tempOptions[$tempNewsArticleNumber]['newsId'] == $id)
            {

                $singlePost = $tempOptions[$tempNewsArticleNumber];
            }
        }
        return $singlePost;
    }

} //end class
?>
```

I am calling this from another file named `testing`:

```
include_once("plugins/newsarticles/controller/NewsArticleController.php");
echo "out";
echo NewsArticleController::newsArticleHome();
```

Comment: How are you *calling* this function?

Comment: Oh sorry lol, I probably should have added that.
It's in another file named testing Below is the other files full contents

include_once("plugins/newsarticles/controller/NewsArticleController.php");
echo "out";
echo NewsArticleController::newsArticleHome();

Comment: there you go. you're calling it as a static method. static methods don't have a `$this`. you can only use `$obj->method()`-type calls if you want to use `$this`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I deleted the comment when I realised I was given the solution, only half read the answer. :p

Comment: So wait, This should work from the testing file yeah?
echo $NewsArticleController->newsArticleHome();

Provided that I defined that as the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NewsArticleController::newsArticleHome();` is calling the function as if it were a static function.  You need rather to create an instance of the class.

```
$nacont = new NewsArticleController();
$nacont->newsArticleHome();
```